# Submit New Contract to Opensea Not Working

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, opensea, erc721

I am trying to list a new Ethereum smart contract on Opensea. It worked fine on Rinkeby. Its now deployed on mainnet with 10 tokens minted, however when I try and submit it to Opensea here https://opensea.io/get-listed/step-two I get this error "We couldn't find this contract. Please ensure that this is a valid ERC721 or ERC1155 contract deployed on Ethereum and that you have already minted items on the contract."

The contract can be found on Ether scan here https://etherscan.io/address/0x6d9217c153e6Aaf00d379E99BE7A1809ad1e4259

Opensea has not responded to my ticket. Any ideas what Im doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I minted a new single token via Metamask, and it showed up. But it’s missing the initial 10 tokens minted via the contract https://opensea.io/collection/drunk-robots-v2

Comment: Did you resolve this? if so how?

Comment: I actually can't recall how I did it, but if I remember correctly, it resolved itself over a little time